# Hide amp-user-notification on initial page load

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

I'm using amp-user-notification to display a newsletter signup form (via amp-iframe) on desktop and a slimmed down text/cta version on mobile.

The newsletter slides in from the right when you start scrolling on desktop and fades in from the bottom when on mobile. The issue though is that the amp-user-notification container is displayed briefly before you start scrolling. I tried adding a class to the notification with the visibility set to hidden, but that doesn't have any effect.

You can see the issue on our staging site, here:
https://winefolly.staging.wpengine.com/

Here is a pastie with my full code:
https://www.pastiebin.com/5c10ffee0703c

I can't see anything in the docs about hiding the notification initially and looking at the suggested use case of cookie consent, that makes sense, but not in this case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out the issue. I didn't have the opacity and visibility keyframes in my media query (duh!).

Updated code for the animations is:

```
<amp-animation id="showSignup" layout="nodisplay">
<script type="application/json">
{
   "duration": "200ms",
    "fill": "both",
    "iterations": "1",
    "easing": "ease-out",
    "delay": "200ms",
    "direction": "alternate",
    "selector": "#newsletter-slidein",
    "switch": [
      {
        "media": "(min-width: 480px)",
        "keyframes": { "opacity": "1", "visibility": "visible", "transform": "translateX(-365px)" }
      },
      {
        "keyframes": { "opacity": "1", "visibility": "visible" }
      }
    ]
 }
</script>
</amp-animation>
<amp-animation id="hideSignup" layout="nodisplay">
<script type="application/json">
 {
    "duration": "200ms",
    "fill": "both",
    "iterations": "1",
    "direction": "alternate",
    "easing": "ease-in",
    "delay": "0",
    "selector": "#newsletter-slidein",
    "switch": [
      {
        "media": "(min-width: 480px)",
        "keyframes": { "opacity": "0", "visibility": "hidden", "transform": "translateX(-15px)" }
      },
      {
        "keyframes": { "opacity": "0", "visibility": "hidden" }
      }
    ]
 }
</script>
</amp-animation>
```